# accessing core microarchitecure in QEMU, HOW?

Tags: qemu, core

I have two questions:
1) Is QEMU a full system simulator or a virtalization layer?
2) when it installed, Is it possible to access micro architecture elements of a core such as registers ,...?
I need it because i must modify some of a core's register contents during run time (dynamically).
Thanks and regards.